# add resources with the addResource method

Tags: jquery, resources, fullcalendar

Is it possible to add several resources with the addResource method ?

I have try the source :

```js
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addResource', [{
  parentId : '37',
      id: '3701-a',
      title: 'test'
  },{
  parentId : '20',
      id: '2002-a',
      title: 'test'
  }
], true);
```

But it does not work, I have below my existing resources, the resource "_fc1".

[image]

Why ?

Regards,

Comment: As per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/addResource you must pass an object, not an array. If you want to add multiple resources, just use a loop to call addResource enough times.

Comment: Thank you very much, It's works.